# phantomjs is not honoring page break

Tags: phantomjs

phantomjs is not honoring page break, I tried couple of things

```
    p1
    <p><!-- pagebreak --></p>
    p2
    <p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>
    p3
```

But they did not work, do you know any trick to force phantomjs to break the page  ?